# How to get a number to display in alert box rather than NAN

Tags: javascript, alert, nan, parsefloat

I am learning javascript and I made a simple program to convert feet to meters and lbs to kg and I want to display the output using alert boxes in the correct measurements

I checked the variables using typeof and its coming back number but the alert boxes are still saying NAN.

I am new to javascript and Im following along with a udemy course.

```
var kgMark = parseFloat(kgMark); 
var meterMark = parseFloat(meterMark);
var bmiMark = parseFloat(bmiMark);
var feetMark = parseFloat(feetMark);
var lbsMark = parseFloat(lbsMark);

kgMark = lbsMark / 2.2046;
meterMark = feetMark / 3.2808;
bmiMark = kgMark / (meterMark * meterMark);

feetMark = prompt('How tall is mark in feet?');
lbsMark = prompt('How much does mark weigh in pounds?');



alert('Mark is ' + ' ' + kgMark + ' '+ 'kilograms');
alert('Mark is ' + ' ' + meterMark + ' ' + 'meters');
alert('Marks BMI is ' + ' ' + bmiMark);
```

I have tried it several different ways and I am truly stuck. I keep getting the NAN error in the alert box.

Comment: What is `kgMark` in your code? where have you defined it?

Comment: `var kgMark = parseFloat(kgMark);`  What are you expecting this line to do?  You can't parse a variable before its been created...

Comment: `typeof NaN === "number"` btw

Comment: your prompts are after you use them?

Comment: try this instead of kgMark and other variables: `isNaN(kgMark) ? kgMark : defaultValue`, where defaultValue is the value you want to show in case your variable is NaN

Comment: Just a little rearranging needed: https://codepen.io/frobinsonj/pen/RwwRJEx - Use `parseFloat()` after you've got your values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First take a value then perform every logic:

```
var feetMark = prompt('How tall is mark in feet?');
var lbsMark = prompt('How much does mark weigh in pounds?');


feetMark = parseFloat(feetMark);
lbsMark = parseFloat(lbsMark);

var kgMark = lbsMark / 2.2046;
var meterMark = feetMark / 3.2808;
var bmiMark = kgMark / (meterMark * meterMark);

alert('Mark is ' + ' ' + kgMark + ' '+ 'kilograms');
alert('Mark is ' + ' ' + meterMark + ' ' + 'meters');
alert('Marks BMI is ' + ' ' + bmiMark);
```

Comment: Can you add some more information about why your solution is the solution?

Comment: When we parse variable to float, it has no value so it converted to NAN.

Comment: `var kgMark = parseFloat(kgMark);` - `kgMark` is undefined here.. It'll work because you redefine it later but it's pointless

Comment: I did but I have less than 15 reputation so it does not change publicly I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the code to the following worked:

```
var feetMark = parseFloat(prompt('How tall is mark in feet?'));
var lbsMark = parseFloat(prompt('How much does mark weigh in pounds?'));

kgMark = parseFloat(lbsMark / 2.2046);
meterMark = parseFloat(feetMark / 3.2808);

var bmiMark = parseFloat(kgMark / (meterMark * meterMark));

console.log('Mark is ' + ' ' + kgMark + ' '+ 'kilograms');
console.log('Mark is ' + ' ' + meterMark + ' ' + 'meters');
console.log('Marks BMI is ' + ' ' + bmiMark)
```

Whats happening in the code you posted is a mixture of something called `hoisting` and the fact that when you run `parseFloat` on an `undefined` variable, its making those variables `NaN`; which whatever operation you do on it will always remember `NaN`.

So, I would suggest to `parseFloat` the variables when you are sure that you receive some value in it.

I hope this helps.